# Python Parameter Passing

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I'm working on making a modified version of pong for my college class and am having some trouble passing some methods. I believe I have everything set up the way it needs to to be able to do some parameter passing. The code runs fine and stops working just after the while loop in my main function. Any help is appreciated.

```
    import pygame

    SCR_WID, SCR_HEI = 640, 480
    class Player():
            def __init__(self):
                    self.x, self.y = 16, SCR_HEI/2
                    self.x1, self.y1 = SCR_WID-16, SCR_HEI/2
                    self.speed = 3
                    self.padWid, self.padHei = 8, 64
                    self.score = 0
                    self.scoreFont = pygame.font.Font("imagine_font.ttf", 64)

            def scoring(self):
                    scoreBlit = self.scoreFont.render(str(self.score), 1, (0,0,0))
                    screen.blit(scoreBlit, (32, 16))
                    if self.score == 10:
                            print ("player 1 wins!")
                            exit()

            def scoring1(self):
                    scoreBlit = self.scoreFont.render(str(self.score), 1, (0,0,0))
                    screen.blit(scoreBlit, (SCR_HEI+92, 16))
                    if self.score == 10:
                            print ("Player 2 wins!")
                            exit()

            def movement(self):                 
                    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
                            self.y -= self.speed
                    elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
                            self.y += self.speed

                    if self.y <= 0:
                            self.y = 0
                    elif self.y >= SCR_HEI-64:
                            self.y = SCR_HEI-64

                    keys1 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                    if keys1[pygame.K_UP]:
                            self.y1 -= self.speed
                    elif keys1[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                            self.y1 += self.speed

                    if self.y1 <= 0:
                            self.y1 = 0
                    elif self.y >= SCR_HEI-64:
                            self.y1 = SCR_HEI-64

            def draw(self):
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (self.x, self.y, self.padWid, self.padHei))
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (self.x1, self.y1, self.padWid, self.padHei))



    class Ball():
            def __init__(self):
                    self.x, self.y = SCR_WID/2, SCR_HEI/2
                    self.x1, self.y1 = SCR_WID/2, SCR_HEI/2
                    self.speed_x = -3
                    self.speed_y = 3
                    self.size = 8

            def movement(self):
                    self.x += self.speed_x
                    self.y += self.speed_y

                    if self.y <= 0:
                            self.speed_y *= -1
                    elif self.y >= SCR_HEI-self.size:
                            self.speed_y *= -1

                    if self.x <= 0:
                            self.__init__()
                            enemy.score += 1
                    elif self.x >= SCR_WID-self.size:
                            self.__init__()
                            self.speed_x = 3
                            player.score += 1
                    for n in range(-self.size, player.padHei):
                            if self.y == player.y + n:
                                    if self.x <= player.x + player.padWid:
                                            self.speed_x *= -1
                                            break
                            n += 1
                    self.x1 += self.speed_x
                    self.y1 += self.speed_y

                    if self.y1 <= 0:
                            self.speed_y *= -1
                    elif self.y1 >= SCR_HEI-self.size:
                            self.speed_y *= -1

                    if self.x1 <= 0:
                            self.__init__()
                            enemy.score += 1
                    elif self.x1 >= SCR_WID-self.size:
                            self.__init__()
                            self.speed_x = 3
                            player.score += 1
                    for n in range(-self.size, enemy.padHei):
                            if self.y1 == enemy.y1 + n:
                                    if self.x1 >= enemy.x1 - enemy.padWid:
                                            self.speed_x *= -1
                                            break
                            n += 1

            def draw(self):
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (112,138,144), (self.x, self.y, 8, 8))

    SCR_WID, SCR_HEI = 640, 480
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCR_WID, SCR_HEI))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Justin's pong")
    pygame.font.init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 60
    player = Player() 
    ball = Ball()
    enemy = Player()

    def main():
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                                    print ("Game exited by user")
                                    exit()
        backgroundimage = pygame.image.load("background.png")
        ball.movement()
        player.movement()
        enemy.movement()
        position = (0,0)
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(backgroundimage, position)
        ball.draw()
        player.draw()
        player.scoring()
        enemy.draw()
        enemy.scoring1()
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(FPS)

    main()
```

Comment: Dude - indentation! Use 4 spaces, no more, no less.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing beyond your `while` loop will be executed until the loop as been completed.

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
    print(i)
    i += 1
print('Finished!')
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
Finished!
```

Comment: Also his for loop has a similar problem (not a breaking problem but not doing what he thinks it is either): n += 1 in a for with a range does not alter for n in range:

Comment: I understand what you're saying by saying that I need to complete the loop, I'm just not sure I understand how to do that. Wouldn't I have to do something with `False` to counteract the `True` or is that way off?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `pygame` module, but it seems that the `while` loop isn't even needed. @JustinFarr

Comment: @zachgates7 yes, with pygame you need a while True (to keep looping the game until it hits an end game situation). JustinFarr is just mistaken on a number of fundamental issues such as what should be wrapped in the while loop.